# How to fix the formatting in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, formatting

Apparently there are some [problems](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1068325/) with formatting in Eclipse Mars. An [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3285) has already been opened. Also there seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303519) that has supposedly been fixed.

My problem is that source code that is inside braces does not get indented. I'm using:

```
Version: Mars Milestone 6 (4.5.0M6)
Build id: 20150326-0744
```

Does anyone have a workaround? Thanks.

edit: this is what the formatter does:

```
public class Junk {
int foo() {
int x=1;
System.out.println(x);
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    x++;
    for(int j=0;i<2;i++) {
    x++;
    }
}
return x;
}
```

}

Comment: First, upgrade to the released version of Mars.  Some of the formatting bugs may have been fixed there. If not, please be specific. Give an example of what isn't working and how you'd expect it to be formatted. Most of the links you posted are either working for me or are marked as fixed.

Comment: ide updated a few days ago. nothing new available by that method. are you suggesting newer?

Comment: OK. `Mars Milestone 6 (4.5.0M6)` is not the release build. So, you must be running something newer. What bug in particular are you hitting?

Comment: code inside a method is not indented at all.

Comment: To reiterate what @AndrewEisenberg said: A) get the latest *release* (not a Milestone), and B) give specific example(s)

Comment: where is latest release? i've been looking for it with no luck. specific example is: "code inside a method is not indented at all".

Comment: latest release: https://eclipse.org/downloads/ formatter bug example (provided by OP): https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3285

Comment: all i see there is: Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200 at least that is the se version.

Comment: can you add add current format and, what is the format you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said it is the bug of eclipse already I faced. I could fix that using version 4.5.1.

Please use following link to download bug fixed version.
http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/commit/?h=R4_5_maintenance&id=3a54e1075910dfdcd0ae404611dd26506404e6e7

Comment: i changed my preferences from tabs only to spaces only and that seemed to work.